# CountAsync behavior in Soft Delete in EF Core 6

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

In this case, I have an application that needs **Soft Delete** concept for reasons.
I add `IsDeleted` flag and `DeletedDate` to all entities that have primary key and I use GlobalFilter to filter deleted data:

```cs
var entitiesAssembly = typeof(BaseEntity).Assembly;
modelBuilder.ApplyGlobalFilters("IsDeleted", false);
modelBuilder.RegisterAllEntities<BaseEntity>(entitiesAssembly);
```

`ApplyGlobalFilters` method is a customize function I brought it below:

```cs
public static void ApplyGlobalFilters<T>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, string propertyName, T value)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        var foundProperty = entityType.FindProperty(propertyName);
        if (foundProperty != null && foundProperty.ClrType == typeof(T))
        {
            var newParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType);
            var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(newParam, propertyName), Expression.Constant(value)), newParam);
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(filter);
        }
    }
}
```

All things are good and work correctly except scenario that I explained in the following;
I have `EntityB` that has a foreign key of `EntityA`. I soft delete a row of `EntityA` that its primary key keep in `EntityB` as foreign key. Let's bring an example to make it sense:

This is Table of `EntityA`:

| ID | Title | IsDeleted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NameA | true |
| 2 | NameB | false |

This is Table of `EntityB`:

| ID | EntityAId | Title | IsDeleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | TitleA | false |
| 2 | 2 | TitleB | false |
| 3 | 2 | TitleC | false |

Now when I use `Context.EntityB.ToList()` the SQL query generated by **ef** is as follows:

```sql
SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[EntityAId], [d].[Title], [d].[IsDeleted]
FROM [EntityB] AS [d]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [d0].[Id], [d0].[Title], [d0].[IsDeleted]
    FROM [EntityA] AS [d0]
    WHERE [d0].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t] ON [d].[EntityAId] = [t].[Id]
WHERE [d].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
```

And it returns rows 2 and 3 and it's correct because the foreign key of 1 is soft deleted. But when I use '.Count()' of the same `IQueryable` it returns 3. But I'm looking for a way to not calculate deleted relation row in getting `Count()`.

At last, I should say, I know that I have to use cascade soft delete for this kind of scenario but I got curious to see if is there any solution for this scenario?!

Comment: Actually it should not filter when you call `Context.EntityB.ToList()`, it is filtered because relation to `EntityA` is `Required` and EF Core uses `INNER JOIN` which filter out main records. Better to make it optional for consistency.

Comment: Using global query filter for SoftDelete concept breaks consistency in some cases as @SvyatoslavDanyliv said.
You can check [this part](https://github.com/Milvasoft/Milvasoft/tree/master/Milvasoft.DataAccess.EfCore) of my library for a more reasonable SoftDelete implementation.

Comment: @bugrakosen Thank you for your reference; I will check this out.